# Recommend a Photoshop version for my old laptop

Tags: windows, photoshop

I want to buy a Photoshop license, but not the most recent one. I need an older version that would run smoothly on my old laptop.
I will list my computer specification below, please recommend the version number that would run very fast on my system. Performance for me is more important than modern features.

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- 64 bit
- Service Pack 1
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M
- CPU @ 2.5GHz  2.5GHz
- RAM: 6GB

Comment: Don't think you'll be able to since Adobe moved to the subscription method of licensing.  Would The Gimp (gimp.org) work?

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I will try that. However I need some basic training on Photoshop. Maybe I could find old version of it somewhere. I would appreciate if you have any suggestion on the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Photoshop Elements 2019, US$ 100

The [system requirements](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-elements/tech-specs.html) list

✓ Windows 7 with Service Pack 1

✓ 64-bit versions only (32-bit not supported)

✓ processor with SSE2 support (the i5-2450 has SSE2 support)

✓ 1.6GHz or faster

✓ 4GB of RAM (8GB recommended)

So you're well above the minimum requirements.

> would run very fast on my system

Well, that's not possible to tell, to be honest, because that depends

a) on the hard disk drive type. An SSD may speed up things by a factor of 10

b) on the size of images you edit.

c) what you define as very fast (may be much different that what I think is very fast)

Let me elaborate on b) for a moment. You have 6 GB of RAM. 1 GB will be used by Windows on its own. The remaining 5 GB can be used by Photoshop. 2 GB will be needed by Photoshop itself for the windows, menus, pens and brushes etc. The remaining 3 GB can be used for images.

If you want to be able to to 19 undo steps, there's 150 MB per image. An RGBA image has 4 channels, so you have 37.5 MB per channel. This means you can edit images up to √37.5M ~ 6000x6000 pixels.

It should be sufficient for

> some basic training on Photoshop

Comment: I didn't know about ADOBE PHOTOSHOP ELEMENTS 2019, I looked it up. I think I need to learn a version of photoshop CC

Comment: Can you make a quick analysis on my hardware and requirements for smooth performance of photoshop CC? Will 2017 version work better on my hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Photoshop CC 19, US$ 10 per month

The [system requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html) list:

✓ Windows 7 with Service Pack 1

✓ Intel® Core 2 or AMD Athlon® 64 processor (the i5 is superior to these)

✓ 2 GHz or faster processor

✓ 2 GB or more of RAM (8 GB recommended)

? OpenGL 2.0-capable system

For the rest, see my [other answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/62448/1935), since the same principles apply.